# 4 Channel Relay Module Set to LOW activates relay?

Tags: arduino, relay

I seems that my [4 channel relay module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5O8) is acting the opposite of how I thought it should act. When I do use the Arduino "digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);" essentially turning power on to the relay, the relay switch is open. When I write "digitalWrite(relay, LOW);", it closes. How is that correct? I thought when you energized the coil, the switched closed to complete the circuit, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable on the Arduino, so please excuse me if this sounds odd: Are you maybe connecting to the NO terminal of the relay instead of the NC terminal? Is there anything in the documentation that suggests that the switch is inverted or if it sinks currents rather than source it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relay module inputs are active low. They are designed to work that way.

[image]

Comment: So I didn't connect it backwards or anything? Doesn't low mean no voltage? How will the coil energize without voltage?

Comment: The input is the low side of a optocoupler and led. Low means close to Ground Potential or Voltage. Since the high side of the optocoupler and led is connected to VCC, setting the pin High means both sides of the circuit are at the same High/VCC potential. Setting it low means there is a difference in voltage. By setting the pin low, you create the ground for the optocoupler, allowing current to pass, turning it on. Look for information on Arduino LEDs with Common Anode and Common Cathode for more information on how it works.

Comment: @MatthewBerman basically, by setting the pin high, you have 5v on both sides of the module input circuit, which means no current passes. When you set the pin low, you have 5v on one side, and 0v at the arduino pin, so current passes, turning the optocoupler on, which turns the relay on.

Comment: @Passerby I see now where you got that schematic. You're right, +1.

Comment: @passerby  +1  I have the Keyes version of this (http://dx.com/p/arduino-compatible-4-channel-relay-shield-module-144762) and it requires a write high to turn on.  Good catch- I would not have thought about it being active low.

Comment: @mikeY the sainsmart is a very common one. I'm surprised there is a clone that's active high. Then again, with DX, you might find out that a year later they switch suppliers and the design changes, which happens often with alot of dx products.